# Programming ARM in mass production

Tags: arm, programming

I am new to embedded development and I am still working my way up from learning Arduino to raw AVR and next to STM32 which uses ARM.

I have a question in my mind which involves the commercial mass production of devices which use ARM.

How is it done? An example from what I've done already is that I programmed my ATMega328 and once it was done, I moved the DIP chip to a breadboard, and the set the circuit and it all worked, but how is that done in the professional ARM world?

What can be used to program an ARM microprocessor and then use it on an actual device? Do we design the whole device with the ARM soldered in and then program the microprocessor straight on the board in commercial devices?

I couldn't really find a good answer online but I hope I am asking the right question.

Comment: It depends on your application, such as do you want to have room for programming cables on board and program boards with firmware, or do you already have an interface to program with it PC, or would you rather pre-program them before soldering, maybe even buy them pre-programmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is In-Circuit Serial Programming (ICSP or ISP).

You connect whatever programming interface the MCU has to some sort of programming header. Then this is connected in production, to a programming device.
When it comes to ARM devices, most commonly used nowadays is SWD (Serial Wire Debug).

Then there are of course more advanced application processors for example, often not using internal flash memory but some external flash memory device. How those are production programmed can differ quite a lot. But for example NXP i.MX 6-7-8 devices that I have worked with, can be connected to a computer via USB and program the flash memory though there.

Then, after the initial programming, many products use software updates where the MCU can write its own memory for updating. Often using some boot loader or dual-bank flash memory.

Comment: I think in production this might also happen on a bed of nails fixture made just for the PCB, rather than a header, which also tests it. There are also special production programming USB-JTAG units which do not need to be connected to a PC and store the program on them. Some are even battery powered.

Answer (score 2):

Microcontrollers based on ARM architecture (Most popular STM32/8) can be programmed in several ways. The most used methods are by using SWD connector or JTAG. Many Nucleo and discovery boards that are based on above-mentioned microcontrollers use either of them or both. The SWD deguggers provided by STlink are very common. You can check their latest version [here](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stlink-v3set.html)

Yes, of course, you can program them after mounting (by using a connector from the SWD pins defined by datasheet of the specific microcontroller)

Answer (score 2):

Many distributors offer programming microcontrollers as a value added service.  For example, Digikey offers programming on certain (many) microcontrollers.

Then the part can simply be soldered to the board during manufacturing.  Digikey has automated equipment to feed controllers, program them in a test fixture, repackage them.

Look at the top paragraph with gray background...
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/ATMEGA328P-MNR/2357090

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if your production is big enough, manufacturers and big distributors can program ICs for you before delivery.